# JSON return format in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, json

Actually my question is simple. I think. But unfortunately, Google can't help me this time.
I want to return a JSON in my view in this format:

```
[[0,"Mark Kordon",null,"My HTML - Mark Kordon"],[1,"John Doe",null,"John Doe Markup"]]
```

How is this possible?

Comment: I think what you want isn't JSON...

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the plugin I was using. The format doesn't mean anything. So looks like the correct answer is from Nick Riggs. But still, this would include the properties. Read JSON. Thanks guys.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370332/how-to-return-json-in-specific-format-in-asp-net-mvc-using-json-with-no-proper

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like all you want to do is return your model from the controller as a JsonResult:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Json(yourModel);
}
```

Comment: Didn't have time to  test it, but wouldn't it also return the properties names?