# How to return JSON in specific format in ASP.NET MVC using Json() with no property names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I am using a charting javascript library that expects its data in a specific JSON format - without property names.
I have an object in my Model that I am using to return the data to the charts. This looks as follows:

```
public class ChartData
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

An action looks as follows:

```
public ActionResult AssetsPerFloor(Guid id)
    {
        var results = from a in surveyRepository.GetAssetsForBuidling(id)
                      group a by a.Room.Floor into g
                      select new ChartData{ Key = g.Key.ToString(), Value = g.Count() };
        return Json(results);
    }
```

This returns JSON in the format `[{"Key":"Main Building","Value":1}]`

However, the chart requires no property names, eg: `[[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]`

Is there anyway I can return the results in this format. I'm sure there's a simple trick to it, but I cant think of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, it needs to return a multi-dimensional array. Try this :

```
var results = 
    (from a in surveyRepository.GetAssetsForBuidling(id)
        group a by a.Room.Floor into g
        select new ChartData{ Key = g.Key.ToString(), Value = g.Count() })
        .Select(x => new string[] { x.Key, x.Value.ToString() };
return Json(results);
```